# AWS Redshift: Wrong escape on unload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I found wrong escape on unload specific text.

When text has `(` as last character, escape faild like below.

```
# expected
"hoge","huga","longtext (","2016-01-01"

# actual
"hoge","huga","longtext (\,"2016-01-01"
```

And the query to unload is

```
UNLOAD ( ${SELECT_STATEMENT} )
TO 's3:// ${S3_PATH} '
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id= ${ACCESS_KEY_ID} ;aws_secret_access_key= ${ACCESS_KEY} '
DELIMITER ','
ALLOWOVERWRITE
ESCAPE
ADDQUOTES
```

Do you know how to avoid this problem?